# add an activity sheet/UI Alert dialog before initiating an operation in UIView

Tags: ios, uialertview, uiactionsheet

In an app i am developping I have a view which first appears whenever the user imports a doc to the app. What I want is to have a dialog box appear(could be an **UIAlert or Activity sheet menu**) asking the user if he really wants to import that file( Yes or cancel). I would like to know **how to make the UIAlert/Actionsheet menu appear** before the import action is performed, and **how to assign an action** to be done when user clicks on either Yes or No, or "Change file

The view that appears is called ProgressBarView.m/h. In it is the viewdidload like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.progressBar.progressTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153.0/255 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
    self.progressBar.progress = 0.0;
     /*progressValueLabel  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", (self.progressBar.progress * 100)];*/

    self.progressTimer  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3f
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(changeProgressValue)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];

}
```

This is then called in the app delegate when the import starts in the appdidFinishLaunchwith options:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        **[self handleImportURL:url];** // this is the function that handles the import
    }
```

The function that does the import and calls the progressView is as follows:

```
- (void)handleImportURL:(NSURL *)url
{

    // Show progress window
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    __block PVProgressViewController * progressController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"kProgressViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = progressController;

    // Perform import operation
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        NSError *outError;
        NSString * csvString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&outError];
        NSArray * array = [csvString csvRows];
        [[PVDatabaseController sharedController] importArray:array progressHandler:^(float progress) {
            progressController.progressBar.progress = progress;
        }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.window.rootViewController = controller;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: So you want to know how to present a UIAlertView or a UIActionSheet?

Comment: I wanted to know how to have an action sheet appear the import view shows, giving the option to either initiate import or cancel the action.If possible i wanted to see how it can be done with an alertview too.

Comment: In application launch time only u want?

Comment: i think it should appear before/in the **handleImportURL** is called since it is the function that performs the import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your NSURL as an ivar, and call your `handleImportURL:` method in the appropriate `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate{
    NSURL *_importURL;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   _importURL = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        [self confirmImportAlert];
    }
}
```

UIActionSheet:

```
- (void)confirmImportAlert {
     UIActionSheet *myActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
     myActionSheet.delegate = self;
     [myActionSheet showInView:self.window];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
        //initiate import
        [self handleImportURL:_importURL];
    }
    else{
        //don't initiate import
    }
}
```

UIAlertView:

```
- (void)confirmImportAlert {
     UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" message:@"Your Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
     [myAlertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
        //initiate import
        [self handleImportURL:_importURL];
    }
    else{
        //don't initiate import
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. when i implement these functions in the app delegate....the actionsheet doesn't show up

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What's the behavior? And are you using UIActionSheet or UIAlertView?

Comment: i tried both and neither does popup when the PVProgressViewController(See the handleImport function) launches the import

Comment: Hello I managed to make it show, but now the problem I can not figure out is how to cancel the import on the action click.(Using Action Sheet)

Comment: Look at the `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method. If the buttonIndex of the UIActionSheet/UIAlertView is your 'Yes' button, call the method that starts the import. If the buttonIndex is the 'No' button, don't call that method.